# Openlayer's drawstart event firing multiple times after drawend occur

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers

I'm editing the [measure](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html) function made available by OpenLayers team, but I facing some problem. I added an option to remove the last added point when the user right click during the `drawstart` event, but after the first draw is finished this option is fired multiple times. If I finish 3 drawings this option is fired 3 times and so on.

I'm using `addEventListener('contextmenu')` to fire the right click event, so I tried to follow [this suggestion](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once) and add a `{once: true}` option, but this didn't work. I also tried to add this option as a listener and on `drawend` event remove the listener using [`unByKey()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Observable.html), but this didn't worked either.

I just can't understand why the `drawstart` event is being fired multiple times.

**My code**

```js
let listener;
draw.on('drawstart', (evt) => {
    // set sketch
    sketch = evt.feature;

    let tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

    listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', (evt) => {
        let geom = evt.target;
        let output;
        if (geom instanceof Polygon) {
            output = formatArea(geom);
            tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
        } else if (geom instanceof LineString) {
            output = formatLength(geom);
            tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
        }
        measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
        measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
    });

    // Remove last vector with right click
    this.map.getViewport().addEventListener('contextmenu', (evt) => {
        console.log("right clicked");
        evt.preventDefault();
        draw.removeLastPoint()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how did you implement your unByKey()?
it should be possible to do something like this:

```
function detectRightclick() {
  console.log("right clicked");
  evt.preventDefault();
  draw.removeLastPoint()
}
```

then, on drawstart:

`this.map.getViewport().addEventListener('contextmenu', detectRightclick)`

and, on drawend:

`this.map.getViewport().removeEventListener('contextmenu', detectRightclick)`

This is assuming this.map is the map, and you always fire the drawend, when the draw ends (thinking about cancelling the drawing without a drawend being fired)

Comment: Both assumptions are correct. The `unByKey()` was implemented the same way as the measure example shows, inside the `drawend` event, and the listener was created as: `listener2 = this.map.getViewport()...`. Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you very much.